# Is Refactoring Possible for this kind of method?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to refactor this method, I feel the readability is good for this method.. But the number of lines is huge considering the operation it is doing.  Any suggestions?

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetOptions(OptionSource source)
    {
        var options = new List<string>();

        if (source.IsOption1Selected)
        {
            options.Add("Option 1");
        }

        if (source.IsOption2Selected)
        {
            options.Add("Option 2");
        }

        if (source.IsOption3Selected)
        {
            options.Add("Option 3");
        }

        if (source.IsOption4Selected)
        {
            options.Add("Option 4");
        }

        return options;
    }
```

Comment: This can't be your real code.

Comment: @t3chb0t What if I say, it is :-)

Comment: Then there are much bigger issues with the code and design then this _tiny_ method ;-]

Comment: [Use a switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @Mast All suggestions belong in answers, not comments.

Comment: @200_success Honestly, I voted to close this question as stub code. IMO it doesn't fit the [help/on-topic] so it shouldn't be answered.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `yield` like that:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetOptions(OptionSource source)
{
    if (source.IsOption1Selected) { yield return "Option 1"; }
    if (source.IsOption2Selected) { yield return "Option 2"; }
    if (source.IsOption3Selected) { yield return "Option 3"; }
    if (source.IsOption4Selected) { yield return "Option 4"; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you making the method private static? You want only that given class to use this functionality?

Also, your code is not extensible. This method will break if the OptionSource object suddenly has option 5, option6 etc. This violates the Open/Closed principle.

Also it seems that your code always returns a single option, yet you declared the return type as a IEnumerable. Why not string?

To make it extensible, your code should look something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetOptions(OptionSource source)
{
    return source.getOptions(); 
}
```